# Postfix refusing to relay mail from local client

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, python, smtp

I'm trying to get a python script to send mail (using [smtplib.SMTP](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html)), but postfix is refusing to relay the message. I don't use the Ubuntu 10.10 Virtualmin server as a mail server (I happen to use google apps for that), but I want scripts to be able to send mail. Here is the log, with the addresses replsced with generic ones:

```
Apr 11 00:50:27 unimatrix-01 postfix/smtpd[25212]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 11 00:50:27 unimatrix-01 postfix/smtpd[25212]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 554 5.7.1 <example@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<noreply@example.info> to=<user@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<unimatrix-01.example.com>
Apr 11 00:50:27 unimatrix-01 postfix/smtpd[25212]: lost connection after RSET from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 11 00:50:27 unimatrix-01 postfix/smtpd[25212]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

I have already tried with no success, to fix this by running # dpkg-reconfigure postfix according to the [Ubuntu Docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/postfix.html). How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Update: Interestingly, apps using PHP can send mail just fine. So, I suspect it has something to do with postfix requireing authentication locally. This is not necessary as I am use sole user of this VP. I hope this helps with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you permit local networks to relay emails without authentication.

First of all, the following command, should include **permit_mynetworks**

```
sudo postconf smtpd_recipient_restrictions
```

Then check if *127.0.0.1* is in *$mynetworks*. Just do,

```
sudo postconf mynetworks
```

and check if *127.0.0.1* is there.

Comment: Works for mee too added `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks` to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and now `python smtplib` works to relay mail sent to localhost on to a given a `relayhost`.

Comment: +1 @here, thanks for that. It saved me a frustrating evening!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you aren't setting mydomain anywhere, and thus are not telling postfix where it can deliver mail.

You essentially need to set mydomain = gmail.com and then add gmail.com or $mydomain to mydestination.

Make sure to reload/restart postfix

Comment: PHP apps can setil send mail via mail(). Would your guess affect that as well?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, I know I've seen this exact relay error before and this was the problem. Are you positive PHP is using postfix to send out? I would say try making the changes and see if this fixes it, but that my first recommendation.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, and now postfix thinks that it's hosting the mailboxes for gmail.com Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table

Comment: Try setting mydomain to your domain but adding/keeping gmail.com in mydestination, also try adding to main.cf: debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1

Answer (score -1):

I was having issue when sending email from squirrelmail web interface. it said:

```
relay access denied
```

I fixed it by removing the following entry from my `/etc/hosts`:

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```